# How to await an object inside IObservable with a specific property value?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, c#-5.0

To clarify, i have a method:

```
public static IObservable<Node> GetNodes()
    {            
        var computers = GetComputersInLan();
        return computers.Select(computerAddress => GetNode(computerAddress));
    }
```

GetComputersInLan method returns IObservable of IPAddress

```
private static IObservable<IPAddress> GetComputersInLan()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task<PingReply>>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
        {
            Ping p = new Ping();
            ipBytes[3] = (byte)(++ipBytes[3]);
            IPAddress address = new IPAddress(ipBytes);
            tasks.Add(p.SendPingAsync(address, 2000));
        }
        return tasks.ToObservable().Where(x => x.Result.Status == IPStatus.Success).Select(y => y.Result.Address);
    }
```

GetNode method constructs a Node.

```
private static Node GetNode(IPAddress ipAddress)
    {
       return new Node(ipAddress, (IHandler)Activator.GetObject(typeof(Handler), "tcp://" + ipAddress + ":1337/handler"));
    }

public class Node
{
    private IHandler Handler { get; set; }
    public IPAddress Address { get; set; }
    public int AvailableCores { get; set; }

    public async Task<TResult> Invoke<TResult>(Func<TResult> method)
    {
        AvailableCores--;
        var result = await Task.Run<TResult>(() => Handler.Invoke(method));
        AvailableCores++;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Handler is a remote computer, and AvailableCores represents its cpu cores.

What I want is to await method GetNodes to return the first Node that has more than 0 AvailableCores.

```
await GetNodes().FirstAsync(node => node.AvailableCore > 0)
```

But what happens, is that after enough calls to method Invoke, instead of waiting for cores to become available, it fires an exception "sequence contains no elements".

Comment: Can you post the code for GetComputersInLan and GetNode?

Answer (score 1):

That is expected behavior for this method.  `FirstAsync` will only check the current state of the items you pass to it, either returning the first match or throwing the exception you are encountering if there is no match.

You will have to manage the case of waiting until a core becomes available yourself.  You could try `FirstOrDefaultAsync` to return null instead of throwing an exception when all cores are busy.  From there, you will need some scheme to detect when a core becomes available for the next unit of work, be that an event or polling.

Comment: Polling is the exactly what i'm trying to avoid, and as for event, aren't observables made to improve events?

Comment: Use `ManualResetEvent` to signal a core is available.

Comment: Using ManualResetEvent with await or Rx is Doing It Wrong™ - depending on how you architect it, either the Amb or SelectMany are the operators you want here.

Comment: @IvanMilutinović Observables allow you to compose events and are somewhat of an alternative to events. They aren't magic; you still have to provide some way to notify that a "core became available".

Comment: @GideonEngelberth I realize what I have to do, it is the how, that's bothering me :) The question remains. Is it possible to do it with just Rx

Comment: @PaulBetts could you please expand on this?